# How to fetch data from a database through a web service URL in VS 2017

Tags: database, visual-studio, web, service, fetch

I am new to this, I have a web service someone set for me in a distant server where a database resides, I have:

- web service URL
- username
- password
- universe
- 1 parameter which is person's ID.

  Query is all set, all I need to input is the person's ID for it to return the phone, so basically I need to retrieve persons phone number based on his/her ID and save that returned string as an string variable to be further put in a text box.

  Would be ideal to have this executed when a form is loaded, don't know if that is possible.

Searched many sites and none explained how to proceed with plain Visual Basic/.net forms, only ASP and C#.

Hope my description is good, I am using VS 2017.

Please help.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Probably by adding **Service Reference** of that WebService URL and then you could call the methods after creating instance of the same to fetch the result.

Comment: I did that already, what I don't know how to do is the syntax for the parameter and method declaration.